# xhtml to string in spring boot using jackson xml mapper

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

i tired in xml mapper please help me how solved this problem

my.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olOVb.png) my.xml

i want to make return json like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVYKl.png) return

How make like the picture

Comment: Welcome to SO! :-) If you like to share code with us, please provide it as text and not  as an image. Also describe what problem you are facing. You should have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.